How to get the correct disk space used by a column?
I'm having trouble reconciling differing answers given by Postgres about the size of a column. Basically, there are two ways I can think of to get the answer; the first as described in this thread is what I'd call a "bottom up" approach, by summing up the reported storage size for each tuple in a column. In theory, that should sum up to the total column storage used on disk. The second method would be the "top down" approach: getting the total table size, dropping the column and getting the total table size again (VACUUM FULL after each just for good measure). The difference between before and after is the actual column size for sure (right??).
Both approaches should arrive at the same result. But they don't.
Here is my methodology:
DROP TABLE size_test;
CREATE TEMP TABLE size_test AS
SELECT
--  baseline
--  a::SMALLINT
--  a::INTEGER
--  a::BIGINT
FROM generate_series(1,10000) a
;

VACUUM FULL size_test;
SELECT (pg_table_size('size_test'));

-- bottom up:
SELECT
    sum(pg_column_size(a))
FROM size_test st
;

Running that sequence above for each of the four scenarios (the first is a table with no columns as a baseline) gives these results:
+------------------------------------|
|scenario | "top down" | "bottom up" |
+------------------------------------|
|baseline |286720      |             |
|SMALLINT |368640      |20000        |
|INTEGER  |368640      |40000        |
|BIGINT   |368640      |80000        |
+---------+------------+-------------+

And that shows that despite the datatype/size, the consumed space seems to be the same → 81920. And that never matches the "bottom up" number.
Is my methodology flawed? Is there a nuance in pg_table_size that I am missing? Is there a nuance in how storage actually works that I am unaware of? Which is the right answer?

What about space consumed by secondary indexes that hold copies of the data in that column?

There are multiple factors you didn't consider. Storage is a lot more sophisticated.
Most importantly: alignment padding.
The minimum added size per row for user columns is MAXALIGN (typically 8 bytes) - unless it's 8 or fewer null values. See:

How much disk-space is needed to store a NULL value using postgresql DB?

So it matters not which of the three columns you add. Each is <= 8 bytes, so you always add 80000 bytes for your 10000 rows - plus some overhead per data page for added pages, which results in 81920 bytes in the example.
And the simple example doesn't even touch on compression, varlena types, "packed" format, TOAST, null storage ...
Related:

Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL
How many records can I store in 5 MB of PostgreSQL on Heroku?


I actually suspected exactly this and I raised the question because I believe that the results from pg_column_size are misleading to say the least. I've found several Stack threads that mention using it to answer the question of how much disk space is being used by a column... and it seems as though thats NOT correct. I'm not sure what value it gives if it doesn't reflect reality and is easily misunderstood...

pg_column_size() does what it's supposed to do. But storage size is lot more sophisticated than the raw size of an isolated value.

@AlexiTheodore alignment padding doesn't apply to each field in isolation, so how could pg_column_size, which deals with isolated fields, accurately report it?  And how can we evaluate other stack answers which are alluded to, but never actually referenced?

I agree and understand what pg_column_size() does - the question is what is the point of it and does it have the potential to mislead or confuse people?
Example stack answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54687201/9819342

@AlexiTheodore: None of the answers over there are very precise. That's not the fault of pg_column_size(), that's the fault of said answers. In their defense, for a text column (with possibly large values, and no additional alignment padding) overhead becomes less important than for your small, fixed-size integer columns, that possibly require additional alignment padding. Plus, you would not run a seq scan over the table (like it makes sense for variable-length columns) you just multiply size * rows (minus null columns) for this simplistic approach.
